# launchd gives me " No such file or directory" error

Tags: macos, plist

my .plist looks like below ... In /var/log.system.log I can see

```
(com.example.exampled[24728]): posix_spawn("/usr/local/bin/ruby /Users/radek/Sites/sinatrasvn/web.rb", ...): No such file or directory
(com.example.exampled[24728]): Exited with exit code: 1
(com.example.exampled): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

but if I run `/usr/local/bin/ruby /Users/radek/Sites/sinatrasvn/web.rb` the script works fine. Any idea?

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN       http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
       <plist version="1.0">
       <dict>
            <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.exampled</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
                 <string>/usr/local/bin/ruby /Users/radek/Sites/sinatrasvn/web.rb</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
       </dict>
       </plist>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`launchd` doesn't use the shell to run programs; it uses the `exec` system call.  This is why the plist you have above uses an array.

You are setting a single element of that array to a string containing a space, which leads `launchd` to attempt to `exec("/usr/local/bin/ruby /Users/radek/Sites/sinatrasvn/web.rb")` — which, sure enough, is not the name of a file.  Instead, you want to set the array:

```
    <array>
                 <string>/usr/local/bin/ruby</string>
                 <string>/Users/radek/Sites/sinatrasvn/web.rb</string>
    </array>
```

This will pass the paths as individual arguments to `exec()`, and the right thing will happen.

Comment: wow.Nicely put.Thank you. Do I have to call `launchctl load  /Users/radek/Library/LaunchAgents/sinatra.plist` after reboot or it is good enouth to call it once?

Comment: Everything in ~/Library/LaunchAgents will be automatically loaded every time you log in, so `launchctl load ...` is only needed for the current login session (or you could just log out & back in).  BTW, for locally-developed launchd items like this, you should probably use "local." instead of "com.example." as a label prefix.

Comment: Absolutely stellar answer man.  Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

I have a exec file that is basically a self hosting service. It triggers without problems when I run it from Terminal with the code `/Users/user/Public/node_modules/codem-transcode/bin/codem-transcode -c /Users/user/Public/tmp/config.json`

So I created a plist script that I want to run on startup, and I stored it in the LaunchAgent folder. Upon running it, I get the "No such file or directory" error.

Here is a picture showing almost all the information I have

[All the information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoBUE.png)

And here is the plist code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.wolftech.transcode.job</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/com.wolftech.transcode.job.err</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/com.wolftech.transcode.job.out</string>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>60</integer>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/user/Public/node_modules/codem-transcode/bin/codem-transcode -c /Users/user/Public/tmp/config.json</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?